# Spring Boot is buffering Flux response

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, server-sent-events, reactor-netty

There is a buffering occurring on what client receives from a rest endpoint with a Flux response. This flux by itself runs as expected: with a delay of 3 seconds, it prints one message at a time.

```
Flux.fromStream(() -> {
    System.out.println("Started");
    return Stream.iterate(0, i -> i + 2).limit(3)
            .map( id -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    return ResponseDTO.builder().message("Sleep failed").build();
                }
                return ResponseDTO.builder().message("Time is "+ id).build();
            });
}).subscribe(value -> System.out.println(value));
```

However, the same Flux, when sent as a response to the client will batch all the messages and send them all at once. This happens for curls from terminal as well.

```
return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .cacheControl(CacheControl.noCache())
        .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
        .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.add("X-Accel-Buffering", "no"))
        .body(Flux.fromStream(() -> {
            System.out.println("Started");
            return Stream.iterate(0, i -> i + 2).limit(3)
                    .map( id -> {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(3000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            return ResponseDTO.builder().message("Sleep failed").build();
                        }
                        return ResponseDTO.builder().message("Time is "+ id).build();
                    });
        }));
```

The behavior is strange since this Flux works as a live stream and sends messages one at a time in both scenarios:

```
Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(3))
                        .map(id-> ResponseDTO.builder().message("Time is "+ id).build()).subscribe(value -> System.out.println(value));`;
```

```
return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .cacheControl(CacheControl.noCache())
        .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
        .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.add("X-Accel-Buffering", "no"))
        .body(Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(3))
                        .map(id-> ResponseDTO.builder().message("Time is "+ id).build());
```

Is there some additional step needed to activate the live streaming in first scenario?

I've tried updating the produces value in the controller mapping, but that makes no difference.

Comment: `Thread.sleep(3000);` Never block thread in reactor environment!!!!

Comment: Use this: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#delayElements-java.time.Duration-